# Hikaricp NPE connection error with Postgres DB and Hibernate

Tags: hibernate, postgresql, playframework-2.0, hikaricp

I am migrating my app from MySQL to Postgres. My app is using Hibernate, HikariCp on PlayFramework. Everything was working fine on MySQL. But when I try to switch to Postgres, I am getting Null pointer exception on :-BaseHikariPool.addConnection

StackTrace :-

```
play.api.UnexpectedException: Unexpected exception[PersistenceException: Unable to build entity manager factory]
    at play.core.ReloadableApplication$$anonfun$get$1$$anonfun$apply$1$$anonfun$1.apply(ApplicationProvider.scala:166) ~[play_2.11-2.3.8.jar:2.3.8]
    at play.core.ReloadableApplication$$anonfun$get$1$$anonfun$apply$1$$anonfun$1.apply(ApplicationProvider.scala:130) ~[play_2.11-2.3.8.jar:2.3.8]
    at scala.Option.map(Option.scala:146) ~[scala-library-2.11.6.jar:na]
    at play.core.ReloadableApplication$$anonfun$get$1$$anonfun$apply$1.apply(ApplicationProvider.scala:130) ~[play_2.11-2.3.8.jar:2.3.8]
    at play.core.ReloadableApplication$$anonfun$get$1$$anonfun$apply$1.apply(ApplicationProvider.scala:128) ~[play_2.11-2.3.8.jar:2.3.8]
Caused by: javax.persistence.PersistenceException: Unable to build entity manager factory
    at org.hibernate.jpa.HibernatePersistenceProvider.createEntityManagerFactory(HibernatePersistenceProvider.java:82) ~[hibernate-entitymanager-4.3.0.CR1.jar:4.3.0.CR1]
    at org.hibernate.ejb.HibernatePersistence.createEntityManagerFactory(HibernatePersistence.java:55) ~[hibernate-entitymanager-4.3.0.CR1.jar:4.3.0.CR1]
    at javax.persistence.Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory(Persistence.java:63) ~[hibernate-jpa-2.0-api-1.0.1.Final.jar:1.0.1.Final]
    at javax.persistence.Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory(Persistence.java:47) ~[hibernate-jpa-2.0-api-1.0.1.Final.jar:1.0.1.Final]
    at play.db.jpa.JPAPlugin.onStart(JPAPlugin.java:38) ~[play-java-jpa_2.11-2.3.8.jar:2.3.8]
Caused by: org.hibernate.HibernateException: com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.PoolInitializationException: Exception during pool initialization
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.hibernate.HikariConnectionProvider.configure(HikariConnectionProvider.java:86) ~[HikariCP-2.3.7.jar:na]
    at org.hibernate.boot.registry.internal.StandardServiceRegistryImpl.configureService(StandardServiceRegistryImpl.java:89) ~[hibernate-core-4.3.0.CR1.jar:4.3.0.CR1]
    at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.initializeService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:206) ~[hibernate-core-4.3.0.CR1.jar:4.3.0.CR1]
    at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.getService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:178) ~[hibernate-core-4.3.0.CR1.jar:4.3.0.CR1]
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.JdbcServicesImpl.buildJdbcConnectionAccess(JdbcServicesImpl.java:265) ~[hibernate-core-4.3.0.CR1.jar:4.3.0.CR1]
Caused by: com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.PoolInitializationException: Exception during pool initialization
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.BaseHikariPool.initializeConnections(BaseHikariPool.java:542) ~[HikariCP-2.3.7.jar:na]
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.BaseHikariPool.<init>(BaseHikariPool.java:171) ~[HikariCP-2.3.7.jar:na]
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool.<init>(HikariPool.java:60) ~[HikariCP-2.3.7.jar:na]
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool.<init>(HikariPool.java:48) ~[HikariCP-2.3.7.jar:na]
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource.<init>(HikariDataSource.java:80) ~[HikariCP-2.3.7.jar:na]
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: null
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.BaseHikariPool.addConnection(BaseHikariPool.java:446) ~[HikariCP-2.3.7.jar:na]
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.BaseHikariPool.initializeConnections(BaseHikariPool.java:540) ~[HikariCP-2.3.7.jar:na]
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.BaseHikariPool.<init>(BaseHikariPool.java:171) ~[HikariCP-2.3.7.jar:na]
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool.<init>(HikariPool.java:60) ~[HikariCP-2.3.7.jar:na]
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool.<init>(HikariPool.java:48) ~[HikariCP-2.3.7.jar:na]
```

persistence.xml  :-

> http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_2_0.xsd"
>                version="2.0">

```
<persistence-unit name="defaultPersistenceUnit" transaction-type="RESOURCE_LOCAL">
    <provider>org.hibernate.ejb.HibernatePersistence</provider>
    <properties>
        <property name="hibernate.dialect" value="org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQLDialect"/> 
        <property name="hibernate.show_sql" value="true"/>
        <property name="hibernate.format_sql" value="true"/>
        <property name="hibernate.use_sql_comments" value="true"/>
        <property name="hibernate.connection.provider_class" value="com.zaxxer.hikari.hibernate.HikariConnectionProvider"/>
        <property name="hibernate.hikari.dataSourceClassName" value="com.impossibl.postgres.jdbc.PGDataSource"/>
        <property name="hibernate.hikari.dataSource.host" value="jdbc:postgresql://127.0.0.1:5432"/>
        <property name="hibernate.hikari.dataSource.database" value="play"/>
        <property name="hibernate.hikari.dataSource.user" value="test"/>
        <property name="hibernate.hikari.dataSource.password" value="test_password" />
        <property name="hibernate.hikari.connectionTestQuery" value="SELECT 1" />                             
    </properties>
</persistence-unit>
```

Build.sbt dependencies:-

```
libraryDependencies ++= Seq(
  javaJdbc,
  cache,
  javaWs,
  javaJpa,
  "org.hibernate" % "hibernate-core" % "4.3.0.CR1",
  "org.hibernate" % "hibernate-entitymanager" % "4.3.0.CR1",
  "org.hibernate.javax.persistence" % "hibernate-jpa-2.1-api" % "1.0.0.Draft-16", 
  "com.impossibl.pgjdbc-ng" % "pgjdbc-ng" % "0.5",   
  "org.scala-lang" % "scala-library" % "2.11.6",
  "com.edulify" %% "play-hikaricp" % "2.0.5"
)
```

Can someone please help me here, I have read many posts on stackoverflow, and HikariCp github page, but couldn't nail down issue.

Thanks!

Comment: Maybe try hibernate.hikari.username and hibernate.hikari.password.  Also, use the ConnectionProvider from Hibernate instead of the one from HikariCP, and upgrade to HikariCP 2.3.8.

Comment: Oh, hibernate.hikari.dataSource.host should be just the hostname (127.0.0.1), you can use hibernate.hikari.dataSource.port for the port number (but it is not necessary as that is the default port).

Comment: @AnkitJain I used hibernate and PostgresSQL do you want to see my config file?